# how to set and display flash messages in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

i am creating a login form in which i have to set a flash message if login fails. i have used the following code to set flash message. 
In actions.class.php inside that a function called executeLogin_process

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Invalid User Name or Password', false);
$this->redirect('login/index');
```

and to display the message in indexSuccess.php

```
<?php if ($sf_user->hasFlash('error')): ?>
  <div class="flash_error"><?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('error') ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

By using this i am not able to display the error messages.i don't know whether i am using the right code or not. Any one please help me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dont use the third parameter on your setFlash method.
This will work:

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Invalid User Name or Password');
```

See: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfUser#method_setflash

If the third parameter is set to false. the flash msg will not persisted to pass a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

```
setFlash ($name, $value, $persist)
```

> $persist true if the flash have to persist for the following request
>   (true by default)

Why did you set the 3rd parameter to `false`?

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Invalid User Name or Password', true);
```

And the 3rd parameter is default `true`, so just:

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Invalid User Name or Password');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove flash message:

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', NULL);
```

If you use a success page or layout, then do `$sf_user->setFlash('error', NULL)`